# Publishing Service Dashboard not showing correctly

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing-service

I have followed the steps to install the publishing service on my sitecore 8.2 initial release.

I have checked the status of the publishing service and it gives me a 0 status which means that it has been installed correctly.

However, after i installed the publishing service module and added the connection string to the include folder to override the url, when i open the publishing dashboard from the launchpad, it looks corrupted:

[image]

and when i click on publish item from the content editor, it gives me the following popup:

[image]

following are the errors showing in the developer tool:

[image]

Any idea what did I miss?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: yes i did and i opened in private window too..

Comment: hi, is the installation missing these js files inside '~/sitecore/shell/client/SPEAK' ? could you please reconfirm.

Comment: Try to re install the module. It might have got fail during installation and some files were not installed

Comment: no the js files are there.. i checked.. and i reinstalled the module, but nothing happened..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by adding the following config file to the **App_Config\Include** folder: `Sitecore.Speak.Components.config`. It was missing in my include folder.